# Gstreamer decodebin not linking to the audioconvert

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I'm trying to play a sound file with gstreamer in Rust (using the [gstreamer crate](https://docs.rs/gstreamer/latest/gstreamer/)).
Here's my code:

```
gst::init().unwrap();

let source = gst::ElementFactory::make("filesrc", Some("source")).expect("Could not create source");
source.set_property_from_str("location", "/home/yuutsuna/Music/m3.mp3");
let decodebin = gst::ElementFactory::make("decodebin", Some("decodebin")).expect("Could not create decodebin element");
let audioconvert = gst::ElementFactory::make("audioconvert", Some("audioconvert")).expect("Could not create audioconvert element");
let sink = gst::ElementFactory::make("pulsesink", None).expect("SINK");
sink.set_property_from_str("device", "alsa_output.pci-0000_02_02.0.analog-stereo");

let pipeline = gst::Pipeline::new(Some("music-pipeline"));
pipeline.add_many(&[&source, &decodebin, &audioconvert, &sink]).unwrap();

gst::Element::link(&source, &decodebin).expect("could not link source and decodebin");
gst::Element::link(&decodebin, &audioconvert).expect("Could not link decodebin and audioconvert");
gst::Element::link(&audioconvert, &sink).expect("Could not link audioconvert and sink");
```

I get the error `Could not link decodebin and audioconvert`

However the following command which do the same is working:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="/home/yuutsuna/Music/m3.mp3" ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! pulsesink device=alsa_output.pci-0000_02_02.0.analog-stereo
```

After looking into the logs and the documentation I found out gstreamer is not able to link the pads between the `decodebin` and the `audioconvert`

```
0:00:00.098766751 13567 0x7fd40c004600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1816:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element decodebin:(any) to element audioconvert:(any)
0:00:00.098808081 13567 0x7fd40c004600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4357:gst_pad_peer_query:<audioconvert:src> pad has no peer
0:00:00.098874314 13567 0x7fd40c004600 INFO               structure gststructure.c:2917:gst_structure_get_valist: Expected field 'channel-mask' in structure: audio/x-raw, rate=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ], channels=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ];
0:00:00.099085743 13567 0x7fd40c004600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:1013:gst_element_get_static_pad: no such pad 'src_%u' in element "decodebin"
0:00:00.099126988 13567 0x7fd40c004600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1270:gst_element_get_compatible_pad:<decodebin> Could not find a compatible pad to link to audioconvert:sink
```

The `decodebin` source pad is a dynamic pad so it's not available right at the creation of the element. I confirmed it by running the `request_pad` method which returned `None`. So I tried to delete the line where I linked the elements then added an action on the event `pad_added` like shown in the [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/pads.html#dynamic-or-sometimes-pads) in order to directly link the pads. However my lambda is never called. Here's the line I used:

```
decodebin.connect("pad_added", true, |value| { info!("new pad {:?}", value); None });
```

I'm not sure if I'm listening to the event correctly. The only examples I found were in C. Either that or there's another issue...

**EDIT**: After a good sleep I just found an [example](https://github.com/sdroege/gstreamer-rs/blob/a1165a74564d0e0f7e67d7669cfac88ae09b5035/examples/src/bin/toc.rs) where instead it uses the `connect_pad_added` method. I'll test this later but I think it's the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I replaced this line:

```
gst::Element::link(&decodebin, &audioconvert).expect("Could not link decodebin and audioconvert");
```

into:

```
let audioconvert_weak = audioconvert.downgrade();
decodebin.connect_pad_added(move |_, src_pad| {
    println!("new pad {:?}", src_pad);

    let sink_pad = match audioconvert_weak.upgrade() {
        None => return,
        Some(s) => s.static_pad("sink").expect("cannot get sink pad from sink")
    };

    src_pad.link(&sink_pad).expect("Cannot link the decodebin source pad to the audioconvert sink pad");
});
```

Instead of linking the 2 elements I set a closure which is called when a pad is added for the `decodebin` element. The code in the closure will then print a message, get the sink pad from my `audioconvert` element (that I passed using a weak reference) and finally link the pads.

Comment: Yes that's the correct solution, decodebin won't have pads from the beginning but will add some dynamically so you can only link to them once they're there. See also the decodebin example from the gstreamer-rs repository: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/blob/main/examples/src/bin/decodebin.rs